# How to view both outlook (exchange) calendars and google shared calendars in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar

I have Outlook 2013 for my work. I also have a google account (not apps), with several calendars and some calendars that are shared with me (view only).

I want to see all. I don't care much where. I tried adding the google calendars to outlook, but the shared ones cannot be added (I don't want/can't make them public).

In Mac, the Apple Calendar app handled this just fine. I created an account profiles to exchange and google and voila! I had all calendars. I want something similar in Windows 7

Comment: Why is this off topic? I thought the previous was because I've asked about an app, but here I'm looking for a general solution

Comment: I thought he asked how to do something in outlook or google-calendar

Comment: http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/index.shtml gSyncit™ is a Microsoft Outlook add-in that allows for the synchronization of Outlook calendars, contacts, notes, and tasks with your Google account.

Comment: I'm not looking for sync, just view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Thunderbird with Lightning and the google and exchange providers.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR:

- Private Google Calendar you own **can** be added to Outlook (read-only).
- Shared Google Calendar where you have read/write access **can** be added to Outlook (read-only).
- Public Google Calendars **can** be added to Outlook (read-only)
- Shared read-only Google Calendar **can not** be added to Outlook.

To add a private Google Calendar you own or shared Google Calendar where you have read and write access:

- go to Calendar in Outlook 2013:
- Right click on Calendar
- select Add Calendar > From Internet

[image]

[image]

The address you put in is your Private Address ICAL in Google Calendar.

For public calendars there will be only one ICAL, so you copy that URL.

[image]

If someone shared a calendar with you, but did not make it public, you will see this message when you click on ICS:

> WARNING: Public access to this calendar has not been enabled. You
>   should change your sharing settings before sharing this address with
>   others.

You will not be able to add these calendars into Outlook.

Please note: Outlook 2013 does not fully support ICAL and view-only is the best way add Google Calendars to Outlook 2013. If you use a sync tool, you will potentially run into integration issues between Outlook 2013 and Google Calendar, especially with recurring meetings. Edit Outlook entries in Outlook, edit Google Calendars in GC. To have read/write access to both calendar types, use your smart phone or a Mac.

Comment: " I tried adding the google calendars to outlook, but the shared ones cannot be added (I don't want/can't make them public)."

Comment: You are telling me there is no ICAL link on the shared calendar? It is also a Google Calendar that is shared with you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If someone shares a calendar but you only have view-only access, you can not add it to Outlook. The ICS link is there, but since it not public, Google will not let Outlook access it.